# Как протестировать веб-приложение локально в различных браузерах?

Tags: javascript, selenium, test-automation, angular4

Разрабатываем небольшой проект на Angular 4 + PrimeNG. Бэкенд - Java-сервлеты + php-скрипты. Приложение должно функционировать только в ЛВС предприятия. Возникла задача определения версий браузеров, ниже которых приложение функционировать не будет. Увы, большинство подобных инструментов ориентировано на тестирование сайтов либо платные (BrowserStack например). Как автоматизировать локальное тестирование веб-приложения на совместимость с браузерами? Как обычно такая ситуация разрешается?

Comment: Установить все браузеры себе и прикрутить Selenium WebDriver :)

Comment: Документацию хоть какую-нибудь читали?..

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать такую проверку один раз, то проще руками проверить во всех браузерах. Если хотите запускать регулярно, то пишите автотесты

Comment: Спасибо @suit, значит все-таки Selenium, больше вариантов не предвидится.